# Finding $P(X=2)$

Tags: probability

Rolling a dreidel intil getting the same result twise continuity, lex $X$ be the number of the rolling,

> Find $P(X=2)$

My try

$$2\leq X<\infty$$

$$X\sim G (1/4)$$
$$\Longrightarrow(1-1/4)^{2-1}\cdot1/4=3/16$$

But the answer should be $1/4$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rolling the dreidel for the second time there are $4$ possible outcomes. Exactly one of them agrees with the first result.

Answer (score 0):

When rolling the dreidel twice there are sixteen possible outcomes, four of which represent an identical roll on both counts.

Answer (score 0):

$$(X\color{red}{-1})\sim G(1/4)$$

## \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline  & נ &ג&ה&פ\\\hline
  נ & * \\\hline
  ג & &* \\\hline
 ה & &&* \\\hline
 פ & &&&* \\\hline
\end{array}